# Cannot decode object of class (MSACDeviceHistoryInfo) for key (NS.objects)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have updated Appcenter from 3.2.2 to 5.0.1. Now I am getting exception in IOS when app calling AppCenter.Start with link behaviour "Link frameworks SDKs only". When I downgraded Appcenter I am still getting this exception. Exception disappears only if you delete the application from the phone and reinstall it.

Stacktrace:

```
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException Reason: *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (MSACDeviceHistoryInfo) for key (NS.objects) because no class named "MSACDeviceHistoryInfo" was found; the class needs to be defined in source code or linked in from a library (ensure the class is part of the correct target). If the class was renamed, use setClassName:forClass: to add a class translation mapping to NSKeyedUnarchiver
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e6928ab __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110c68ba3 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x00000001150477d9 -[NSCoder __failWithException:] + 165
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001150479ab -[NSCoder(Exceptions) __failWithExceptionName:errorCode:format:] + 384
    4   Foundation                          0x00000001150e2eb0 _decodeObjectBinary + 646
    5   Foundation                          0x00000001150e5662 -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1752
    6   Foundation                          0x00000001150273ad -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 161
    7   Foundation                          0x00000001150e3898 _decodeObjectBinary + 3182
    8   Foundation                          0x00000001150e22d2 _decodeObject + 163
    9   Foundation                          0x00000001150e21b2 -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:] + 162
    10  Foundation                          0x00000001150e1110 +[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:] + 79
    11  MyApp.iOS                       0x0000000104de107b -[MSDeviceTracker init] + 177
    12  MyApp.iOS                       0x0000000104de0f59 __33+[MSDeviceTracker sharedInstance]_block_invoke + 41
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011ac57a3a _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011ac58db3 _dispatch_once_callout + 20
    15  MyApp.iOS                       0x0000000104de0f2d +[MSDeviceTracker sharedInstance] + 45
    16  MyApp.iOS                       0x0000000104dd0d22 +[MSAppCenter setWrapperSdk:] + 56
    17  MyApp.iOS                       0x0000000105362a69 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
    18  ???                                 0x000000015c3c67ec 0x0 + 5842429932

  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowNSException (System.IntPtr ns_exception) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/i/Versions/16.1.1.27/src/Xamarin.iOS/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:460 
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception (System.IntPtr exc) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/2/s/xamarin-macios/runtime/Delegates.generated.cs:398 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception(intptr)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) ApiDefinition.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr(intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.iOS.Bindings.MSAppCenter.SetWrapperSdk (Microsoft.AppCenter.iOS.Bindings.MSWrapperSdk wrapperSdk) [0x00023] in <d384bd2ae92b44008630788986ca7bdf>:0 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.SetWrapperSdk () [0x00017] in <df2ccd8a0b774ab79c869a1d3fbc3ad1>:0 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.PlatformStart (System.String appSecret, System.Type[] services) [0x00000] in <df2ccd8a0b774ab79c869a1d3fbc3ad1>:0 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.Start (System.String appSecret, System.Type[] services) [0x00000] in <df2ccd8a0b774ab79c869a1d3fbc3ad1>:0 
  at MyApp.App.OnStart () [0x00006] in /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/MyApp/MyApp/App.xaml.cs:112 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Application.SendStart () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Application.cs:346 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication uiApplication, Foundation.NSDictionary launchOptions) [0x00036] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\FormsApplicationDelegate.cs:58 
  at MyApp.iOS.Core.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication nativeApp, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x000e4] in /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/MyApp/iOS/Core/AppDelegate.cs:100 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.xamarin_UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr,intptr&)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (System.Int32 argc, System.String[] argv, System.IntPtr principalClassName, System.IntPtr delegateClassName) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.1.1.27/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:57 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.Type principalClass, System.Type delegateClass) [0x0003b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.1.1.27/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:92 
  at MyApp.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/MyApp/iOS/Main.cs:13
```

I tried to skip linking Microsoft.AppCenter but it did not help

Comment: What happens if you set it to "Don't Link"?

What about if you reference MSACDeviceHistoryInfo before you call AppCenter.Start? Does it give you the same error or the same with a different class it can't resolve?

Comment: Also, have you added all 3 packages? Microsoft.AppCenter, Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics and Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.